# How do I query my database in Windows Forms?

Tags: winforms

I'm creating a small C# app in VS2015.  I need a way for the user to enter a value in a text box, then retrieve the results from the database.  I've already defined the dataset and made the appropriate relations.  There are 9 tables in the dataset. (This generated a whole boat load of code.)
The query will use all 9 tables (I've check the syntax, the query is correct) and return 1 row with 23 columns.  I put a text box and button on the form, the idea is that the buttonClick will execute the query based on what was entered in the text box.  I'd also like to display the results in a list-type fashion. I don't have any idea what to do next.
TIA,
Tracy

Comment: First-off, why are you using VS2015? That's 3 versions out of date now (see: VS2017, VS2019, VS2022) and implies you're targeting a horribly outdated version of .NET Framework instead of the present .NET 6 release.

Comment: "I've already defined the dataset and made the appropriate relations. There are 9 tables in the dataset. "  - this sounds like you're using the (awful) ADO.NET XML/XSD "Typed Datasets" thing... you really are much better-off if you avoid that dead-end approach - is there a reason you're not using Entity Framework?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  The reason I'm not using a more updated version of VS is because I already have VS2015 on my machine, and I wrote, deployed and support an ASP.NET app from VS2015.  So, I thought I could quickly write a little C# windows app on the same platform.

Comment: Wasn't aware that I could use Entity Framework for a WinForm... I used Entity Framework for my ASP.NET application years ago...  maybe I selected the wrong option when I created a new project a few day ago?  I want a desktop app, not a web app.